# Monitoring changes in db2 on client side and updating DB on server accordingly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on an application where I have to consolidate data from clients into a central DB.
The problem is that how can I monitor any data changes (save, update, delete) on clients in real time. I there any way out for that?

I am using Hibernate for data fetching from clients in batches. Checking every row of data and comparing it cell-wise with central DB is not practical. There are about 25 tables that I have to work on.

Appreciate any help or hint.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 cannot do this for you.

You need two things:

1. Catch all write operations in your web application. If you know the actions/URLs/servlets this is your starting point. Or give hibernate listeners a chance.
2. If you need real time update of your web clients. You should look for web sockets. This allows a server-client communication. With a web socket you can tell your web clients to update their data once it has been changed by an other client.